# Showing an inequality with integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integral-inequality

I'm having trouble establishing these inequalities without using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz or Minkowski inequalities. Does anyone have a helpful hint?

$f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[0,1]$:

$$ (a) \hspace{5mm} \Bigg(\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx\Bigg)^{2} \leq \int_{0}^{1} f(x)^{2}dt \int_{0}^{1}g(x)^{2}dt$$

$$ (b) \hspace{5mm} \Bigg(\int_{0}^{1}(f(x) + g(x))^{2}dt\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \Bigg(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2} dt\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} + \Bigg(\int_{0}^{1} g(x)^{2}dt\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Schwarz (aka Bunjakovskij) inequality?

Comment: And the second is Minkowski.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar. But I believe I need to establish these without knowledge of Cauchy-Schwarz/Minkowski inequalities.

Comment: Show that $\langle f, g\rangle:=\int_0^1fg$ is an inner product, then Cauchy-Schwarz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for (a): Consider that

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 [f(x)g(y) - g(x)f(y)]^2\, dx\, dy \ge 0.$$

Expand the double integral above.

Hint for (b): Write

$$\int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]^2\, dx = \int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]f(x)\, dx + \int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]g(x)\, dx.$$

Then by the triangle inequality,

$$\left|\int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]^2\, dx\right| \le \left|\int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]f(x)\, dx\right| + \left|\int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]g(x)\, dx\right|.$$

Use part (a) to show that the first integral on the right-hand side is less than or equal to

$$ \left(\int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]^2\, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 [f(x)]^2\, dx\right)^{1/2}$$

and that the second integral is less than or equal to

$$\left(\int_0^1 [f(x) + g(x)]^2\, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 [g(x)]^2\, dx\right)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for hint (a)... that worked. I'm missing the key step on hint (b), however. Could you expound a little more?

Comment: Hi @clocktower, I've given a more detailed hint for (b). I hope it helps. :)